# Groups or separator in UIAlertController as in new Music app

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to create an UIAlertController as an action sheet that looks like the one from the new Music app in iOS 8.4

What I want is to split my buttons into groups as in the image below. As you can see there is a space between "Crear una lista Genius" and "Añadir a una lista...".

Thank you.

[image: Music app screenshot]

Comment: have you tried to just add 3 or more buttons?

Comment: Yes, my alert controller has six buttons (including the Cancel button at the bottom) and I want special separation between some of them because six buttons are too many of them for a single action sheet without separators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple uses UIAlertController's private APIs, which can be found in [UIAlertController.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertController.h) and  [UIAlertControllerVisualStyle.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIAlertControllerVisualStyle.h) :)

Answer (score 1):

As UIAlertView and UIActionSheet (as well as their respective delegate protocols) are deprecated in iOS 8 we need to use UIAlertController.

still you can look at this utility [JGActionSheet](https://github.com/JonasGessner/JGActionSheet) 
i hope this will help you to full feel your need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The utility you mentioned seems to make what I want. However, I was looking for some "native" solution, using Apple's `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score -1):

For prototyping you can use:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (_) in }))
```

or for a red separator use:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (_) in }))
```